# Prometheus is empty (no targets)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus

**Describe the bug**
After rolling out i try to access prometheus unfortunately no targets are displayed.

**Version of Helm and Kubernetes**:

Helm Version:

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.3", GitCommit:"041ce5a2c17a58be0fcd5f5e16fb3e7e95fea622", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.15.8"}
```

Kubernetes Version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform
:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.5", GitCommit:"9a45ba1752db920873e084791faff8d470278b09", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-19T22:28:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform
:"linux/amd64"}
```

**Which chart**:
prometheus-kube-stack
**Which version of the chart**:
16.6.0

**What you expected to happen**:
Targets and service discovery should contain information

**Changed values of values.yaml** (only put values which differ from the defaults):

values.yaml

```
alertmanagerSpec:
     nodeSelector:
      beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
 ------------------ 
grafana:
  enabled: true
  namespaceOverride: ""

  ## ForceDeployDatasources Create datasource configmap even if grafana deployment has been disabled
  ##
  forceDeployDatasources: false
  
  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
  ## ForceDeployDashboard Create dashboard configmap even if grafana deployment has been disabled
  ##
  forceDeployDashboards: false

  ## Deploy default dashboards.
  ##
  
  storageSpec:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      metadata: 
        name: grafana-pvc
      spec:
        storageClassName: default
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 32Gi
      selector:  
  defaultDashboardsEnabled: true
  
  adminPassword: admin
------------------
kubeStateMetrics:
  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
  
  enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
-------------------
kube-state-metrics:
  namespaceOverride: ""
  rbac:
    create: true
  podSecurityPolicy:
    enabled: true
  
  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux    

--------------------
nodeExporter:
  enabled: true
  
  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    
---------------------
prometheus-node-exporter:
  namespaceOverride: ""
  podLabels:
    ## Add the 'node-exporter' label to be used by serviceMonitor to match standard common usage in rules and grafana dashboards
    ##
    jobLabel: node-exporter
  extraArgs:
    - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(dev|proc|sys|var/lib/docker/.+|var/lib/kubelet/.+)($|/)
    - --collector.filesystem.ignored-fs-types=^(autofs|binfmt_misc|bpf|cgroup2?|configfs|debugfs|devpts|devtmpfs|fusectl|hugetlbfs|iso9660|mqueue|nsfs|overlay|proc|procfs|pstore|rpc_pipefs|securityfs|selinuxfs|squashfs|sysfs|tracefs)$

  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
----------------
prometheusOperator:
  enabled: true

    patch:
      enabled: true
      image:
        repository: jettech/kube-webhook-certgen
        tag: v1.5.2
        sha: ""
        pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      resources: {}
      ## Provide a priority class name to the webhook patching job
      ##
      priorityClassName: ""
      podAnnotations: {}
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      affinity: {}
      tolerations: []
-------------------------
prometheusSpec:

    nodeSelector:
      beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux

    storageSpec:
      
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        metadata: 
          name: prometheus-pvc
        spec:
          storageClassName: default
          accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 32Gi
        selector:
```

**Anything else we need to know**:

EDIT

```
NAME                                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/alertmanager-kube-monitoring-kube-prome-alertmanager-0   2/2     Running   0          9h
pod/kube-monitoring-grafana-6896d856d9-krtgd                 2/2     Running   0          9h
pod/kube-monitoring-kube-prome-operator-74b76d89f7-td5t9     1/1     Running   0          9h
pod/kube-monitoring-kube-state-metrics-7db74b856-p2qmx       1/1     Running   0          9h
pod/kube-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-96mdj           1/1     Running   0          9h
pod/kube-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-lmstk           1/1     Running   0          9h
pod/prometheus-kube-monitoring-kube-prome-prometheus-0       2/2     Running   1          9h

NAME                                               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/alertmanager-operated                      ClusterIP   None           <none>        9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9094/UDP   9h 
service/kube-monitoring-grafana                    ClusterIP   10.0.122.52    <none>        80/TCP                       9h 
service/kube-monitoring-kube-prome-alertmanager    ClusterIP   10.0.115.147   <none>        9093/TCP                     9h 
service/kube-monitoring-kube-prome-operator        ClusterIP   10.0.127.119   <none>        443/TCP                      9h
service/kube-monitoring-kube-prome-prometheus      ClusterIP   10.0.229.127   <none>        9090/TCP                     9h
service/kube-monitoring-kube-state-metrics         ClusterIP   10.0.106.71    <none>        8080/TCP                     9h
service/kube-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter   ClusterIP   10.0.32.130    <none>        9100/TCP                     9h
service/prometheus-operated                        ClusterIP   None           <none>        9090/TCP                     9h

NAME                                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                 AGE
daemonset.apps/kube-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter   2         2         2       2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   9h

NAME                                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/kube-monitoring-grafana               1/1     1            1           9h
deployment.apps/kube-monitoring-kube-prome-operator   1/1     1            1           9h
deployment.apps/kube-monitoring-kube-state-metrics    1/1     1            1           9h

NAME                                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/kube-monitoring-grafana-6896d856d9               1         1         1       9h
replicaset.apps/kube-monitoring-kube-prome-operator-74b76d89f7   1         1         1       9h
replicaset.apps/kube-monitoring-kube-state-metrics-7db74b856     1         1         1       9h
```

If more information is needed please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Andreas ,what do you see under the Service Discovery tab and are you using classic UI or the new UI in prometheus?

Comment: @rohatgisanat Unfortunately, I don't see anything under any UI. By that I mean absolutely nothing (can't show screenshots yet). I usually know that at least something like <JobName (0/2 targets)>. Now it is just an empty page. Applies also to /targets.

Comment: @AndreasEnti Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue and can't seem to find the solution for it :(